# MASM fibonacci sequence based on user input

Tags: assembly, masm, fibonacci, x86-16

I  was sweating half of a night to make this code and then the other half to make it work. After opening many tabs with threads on different forums regarding MASM, fibonacci, stock, division I thought to get your help.
Looks like it got stock in infinite loop because it always displays sequence 
    0, 1,

Even when I type 0 it still doesn't jump to the label specified by conditional jump.

I believe that the problem is most likely in displayFib procedure or displayNum

```
page  55,80
title  Fibonacci                                  [FIB.ASM]
.model small
.stack 100h

.data

msg1 db "Please enter the number of terms in the fibonacci sequence to display:",0DH,0AH,"$" ;message to user
msg2 db "Displaying Fibonacci sequence",0DH,0AH,"$" ; message to user
msg3 db ", ","$"    ; formating - coma
num1 dw 0        ;this is a numeric variable
num2 dw  0      ; this is a numeric variable
input dw  0         ; this is a numeric variable
fibPrev1 DW 1       ; word numeric value n-1 value
fibPrev2 DW 0       ; word numeric value n-2 value
fib DW 0        ; word numeric value
temp    DW 0    ; word numeric value
saveCount DW 0  ;counter storage


.code
extrn clrscr:proc    


main proc
        mov   ax,@data       ; set up data segment
        mov   ds,ax

        call  clrscr            ; clear the screen

    mov   ah,9              ; send message with instructions for user
    mov   dx,offset msg1
    int   21h            

        call keyin          ;gets user input
    SUB AL, 48      ;changes ASCII value into numeric value for further processing
    mov num1 , AX       ;saves user input to variable num1
    call keyin          ;gets user input
    SUB AL, 48      ;changes ASCII value into numeric value for further processing
    mov num2 , AX       ;saves user input to variable num2, so now we have both digits

    ;multiplying num1 10 times

    MOV  CX, 10
    repeat1:            ; loop 10 times
        MOV AX, NUM1    ;copies value of num1 to AX
        ADD input, AX   ;adds value from AX
        DEC CX      ;decrements the counter
        JNZ repeat1 ;loops until counter = 0

    MOV AX, num2        ;adding the value from num2 so if user entered 83, so it was num1=8 num2=3, then we multiplied 8x10=80, so we add 80+3 and we get 83
    ADD input, AX

    call newLine
    mov   ah,9              ; send informative message to user regarding displaying the sequence
    mov   dx,offset msg2
    int   21h 
    call newLine

    call displayFib

    call newLine
    mov   ax,4C00h       ; return to DOS
        int   21h

main endp


newLine proc            ;procedure displays new line
    mov dx,0Dh      ;line feed
    mov ah,2
    int 21h  
    mov dx,0Ah      ;carriage return
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    ret
newLine endp




keyin proc
    mov ah, 1 ; getting a key from the keyboard 
    int 21h 
    ret
keyin endp

displayFib proc
    ;display zero as a 0'th term
    MOV DX, 30h         ; move value 30 hexadecimal to DX, which represents 0
    call display
    MOV AX, input   
    CMP AX, 0        ;if the input is 0 in hexadecimal ASCII value then jump to finish
    JE finish_it

    mov   ah,9              ; formating - coma
    mov   dx,offset msg3
    int   21h       

    ;display the 1st term
    MOV DX, 31h         ; move value 31 hexadecimal to DX, which represents 1
    call display
    CMP input, 1        ;if the input is 1 in hexadecimal ASCII value then jump to finish
    JE finish_it

    MOV CX, input       ;intializing counter, knowing that first 2 terms were displayed already
    SUB CX, 2

    repeat:
        mov   ah,9              ; formating - coma
        mov   dx,offset msg3
        int   21h       

        MOV AX, fibPrev2        ; calculating the n'th term of a sequence    n = (n-1) + (n-2) 
        ADD AX, fibPrev1
        MOV fib, AX
        MOV DX, fib
        MOV saveCount, CX       ;saving the state of the counter as it will be modified in the displayNum
        call displayNum
        ;display the n'th term (current term)
        MOV CX, saveCount       ;restoring state of the counter
        MOV AX, fibPrev1        ; n-1 in the next round of a loop will be n-2
        MOV fibPrev2, AX
        MOV AX, fib         ;n'th term in the next round will be n-1
        MOV fibPrev1, AX
        DEC  CX             ;decrementing counter
        CMP CX, 1
        JL  repeat          ; loop until counter = 0

    finish_it:

    ret
displayFib endp


displayNum proc     ;display numbers including these with more than one digit

    MOV AX, fib ;copying fib to temp
    MOV temp, AX
    MOV CX,0        ;initializing counter to 0
    loop1:
        ;dividng fib by 10 and pushing reminder on the stock
        INC CX          ;incrementing counter
        MOV  ax, temp
        MOV bx, 10
        SUB dx, dx              ;set dx to zero
        DIV bx          ;BX will contain integer division result and DX remainder
        PUSH DX
        MOV temp, BX        ;temp will hold value of itself integer devided by 10
        JNZ loop1

    loop2:
        POP DX
        ADD DX, 30h
        call display
        JNZ loop2       ;loop until all digits on stack are popped and counter =0

    ret
displayNum endp


display proc        ; display of a single character
    mov ah, 6
    int 21h
    ret
display endp


end  main
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. The first mistake that I can spot easily is that `keyin` returns values in `AL` but you subsequently use `AX`. Presumably `AH` still contains `1` at that point, messing up your number.

Comment: Thank you for your note @Jester. According to our professor we supposed to use AH to get user input. I tried to move AH to AX but it gives me error that they dont match (because one is 8-bit and other 16-bit). Could you advise solution?

Comment: One possible solution is to `MOV AH, 0` in `keyin` just before the `RET`.

Comment: Thank you Jester! 
However after trying it it gives me the runtime error
The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction 
CS:055f IP:02d6 OP:f0 06 9b 06 6e
        This makes me lost totally. 
Choose 'Close' to terminate the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO isn't a debugging service, as I said, learn to use a debugger yourself. 
There are a few problems in your code:

1. `AH` not being zero after `keyin`
2. The user's input must be 2 digit (doesn't work for 1 digit)
3. Where your comment says `loop until counter = 0` you are not doing that. Fix: you need `DEC CX; JNZ loop1`.
4. `BX will contain integer division result` - not true, the result is in `AX`, no matter that you used `BX` for the divisor. Fix: you need to adjust the `MOV temp, BX` to `MOV temp, AX`.
5. `JNZ loop1` is missing an instruction that sets the flags, as `DIV` doesn't. Fix: insert `TEST AX, AX`.
6. Your `loop2` is missing the decrement of the loop variable. Fix: insert `DEC CX`.

I believe that was all the changes I had to make to get it working.

Comment: Thank you Jester. I appreciate your suggestions and your help. I downloaded cv debugger and it works so great ! I was able to find all the additional errors and it was much better than trial and error and guessing game that was doing previously. I tended to ignore debuggers but eventually It get back on me.